# Al momento de ejecutar un NamedQuery retorna datos tipo object[] en vez de tipo Clase Java

Tags: jsf, java-ee, cast

Tengo un NamedQuery que solo trae ciertas columnas, el problema es que en mi metodo

```
public List<T> NewEncontarSqlArmado(Map parametros, Asignaturas asignatura) throws ConsultarException {
    try {
        Iterator it = parametros.entrySet().iterator();
        String consulta = "";
        String orden = "";
        boolean all = false;
        int maxResults = -1;
        int firstResult = -1;
        String tabla = entityClass.getSimpleName();
        Map par = new HashMap();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String clave = (String) e.getKey();
            if (clave.contains(";consulta")) {
                consulta = (String) e.getValue();
            } else if (clave.contains(";inicial")) {
                firstResult = (Integer) e.getValue();
                all = true;
            } else if (clave.contains(";orden")) {
                orden = " order by " + (String) e.getValue();

            } else if (clave.contains(";final")) {
                all = true;
                maxResults = (Integer) e.getValue();
            } else {
                par.put(clave, e.getValue());
            }
        }

        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(consulta).setParameter("asignatura", asignatura);

        it = par.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String clave = (String) e.getKey();

            q.setParameter(clave, e.getValue());
        }
        if (all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        return q.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConsultarException(entityClass.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

Me retorna todo en tipo Object[] en vez de la clase que estoy usando en ese momento la cual seria "Archivo" y al momento de tomarlo en mi lista en el bean de archivos, me bota el error de que no pudo tomar el valor tipo objeto en List porque necesita que sea tipo "Archivo".

Espero haya sido claro con mis detalles :/ 
Agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Este es el named Query que tengo

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Archivos.SinArchivo", query = "SELECT a.id, a.codigo, a.nombre, a.descripcion, a.tipo, a.asignatura, a.activo, a.userid, a.fecha, a.tipoarchivo, a.demo, a.filepath FROM Archivos a WHERE a.asignatura= :asignatura and a.activo=true")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @NamedQuery(name = "Archivos.SinArchivo", query = "SELECT a.id, a.codigo, a.nombre, a.descripcion, a.tipo, a.asignatura, a.activo, a.userid, a.fecha, a.tipoarchivo, a.demo, a.filepath FROM Archivos a WHERE a.asignatura= :asignatura and a.activo=true")

el problema esta en que estas llamando a diferentes atributos del objeto (clase) por separado es decir estas llamando `a.id, a.codigo, a.nombre,` cuando podrías llamar `a` en ese caso si te genera el resultado como un objeto si haces un cast

```
 return (List<Archivo>) q.getResultList();
```

si necesitas traer esos objetos especificos *considerando que no son todos los propios de la clase*, entonces siempre te retorana el **arreglo de objetos** ya que todos estos son datos *individuales* en ese caso no tienes de otra si no recorrer ese `Object[]` con un `for` y tomarlos uno por uno agregarlos a una instancia de **Archivo** con los metodos `set() , get()`

reitero que si estos datos que llamas en la consulta son todos los que pertenecen a `Archivos` entonces en la consulta podrias solo devolver

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Archivos.SinArchivo", query = "SELECT a FROM Archivos a WHERE a.asignatura= :asignatura and a.activo=true")
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta; y ok entonces tocara hacer set y get.

Comment: Puedo preguntar por que intentas traer solo algunos? es decir puedes traer el objeto completo y desde java separarlos como desees y es mas facil que recorrer el array de objetos y convertir cada dato a archivo aun mas por que solo estas usando una tabla. (esto no me dejara dormir en las noches e.e)

Comment: Hay un problema de volcado de memoria por la consulta; dentro de la base de datos hay archivos de mas de 500 mb y ahora esta dando problemas. No quieren hacer cambios a la configuracion de Postgresql para que tenga mejor rendimiento, entonces lo que quiero hacer es traer todos menos ese campo.

Comment: A ok eso tiene mas sentido

Comment: Ahora todo tiene sentido por que esta así tu consulta

Comment: Asi es, Muchas gracias por sus respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es que usas `createNamedQuery(consulta)`, que devuelve un objeto Query, pero deberías usar:

```
TypedQuery<Archivo> query= createNamedQuery(consulta,Archivo.class);
...
return query.getResultList();
```

Que sí devuelve una `List<Archivo>`

Comment: Me bota un error que dice que no puede convertir de Query a TypedQuery :/

Comment: No se si sea porque quiero solo ciertas columnas y no todo.

Answer (score 0):

Es que no le estas especificando el tipo de objeto de salida en tu **NamedQuery**, entonces te debería quedar así

```
        List<Archivos> archivosList= null;

        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Archivos.SinArchivo");
        query.setParameter("asignatura", asignatura);
        archivosList= query.getResultList();
```

También tu consulta puede quedar así solo haces referencia a la misma tabla:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Archivos.SinArchivo", query = "SELECT a FROM Archivos a WHERE a.asignatura= :asignatura AND a.activo=true")
```

Podrías probar el siguiente ejemplo tal cual y verificar que te recupere la información sin problema:

```
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public List<Archivos> NewEncontarSqlArmado(Asignaturas asignatura) {
        List<Archivos> archivosList= null;

        Query query = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Archivos.SinArchivo");
        query.setParameter("asignatura", asignatura);
        archivosList= query.getResultList();

        return archivosList;
    }
```

O en tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
public List<T> NewEncontarSqlArmado(Map parametros, Asignaturas asignatura) throws ConsultarException {
    try {
        Iterator it = parametros.entrySet().iterator();
        String consulta = "";
        String orden = "";
        boolean all = false;
        int maxResults = -1;
        int firstResult = -1;
        String tabla = entityClass.getSimpleName();
        Map par = new HashMap();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String clave = (String) e.getKey();
            if (clave.contains(";consulta")) {
                consulta = (String) e.getValue();
            } else if (clave.contains(";inicial")) {
                firstResult = (Integer) e.getValue();
                all = true;
            } else if (clave.contains(";orden")) {
                orden = " order by " + (String) e.getValue();

            } else if (clave.contains(";final")) {
                all = true;
                maxResults = (Integer) e.getValue();
            } else {
                par.put(clave, e.getValue());
            }
        }

        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(consulta).setParameter("asignatura", asignatura);

        it = par.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry e = (Map.Entry) it.next();
            String clave = (String) e.getKey();

            q.setParameter(clave, e.getValue());
        }
        if (all) {
            q.setMaxResults(maxResults);
            q.setFirstResult(firstResult);
        }
        List<Archivos> archivosList= q.getResultList()
        return archivosList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ConsultarException(entityClass.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Chevere bro, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Ahorita tengo listo ya la captura de datos :D